# Creating a simple finger application with batch

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file, cmd

I would like to make a simple batch application that does two things.

1. Asks the user to input a name, example "vega"
2. Runs "finger vega@mail.example.com" and displays the output of that command.

The following does the first thing, but I am not able to output the result from the finger.

```
 @ECHO OFF

 :begin

 echo Enter the name of the user you are looking for:
 set INPUT=
 set /P INPUT=Name: %=%
 finger -l %INPUT%@mail.example.com

 pause
 GOTO begin
```

Comment: It also is an endless loop, which I don't see in your requirements. I'm not quite getting why you delete the variable `INPUT` first when you assign the user-entered value anyway in the next line and what exactly should the `%=%` do? I mean, it's the contents of the variable `=` but if it doesn't exist that simply evaluates to nothing. Also `finger` should output its results if it ran correctly. You're claiming this works for your first requirement but if it does, then it will automatically work for the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set INTERVAL=10
```

echo Enter the name of the user you are looking for:
set /P INPUT=
echo INPUT=%INPUT%
echo Name: %INPUT%

:LOOP
    for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%a IN (`finger -l %INPUT%@mail.example.com`) DO set OUTPUT=%%a
    echo OUTPUT=%OUTPUT%
    if "%OUTPUT%"=="something" (goto LOOPEND)
    call :SLEEP %INTERVAL%
goto LOOP
:LOOPEND

goto :eof

:: -------------- Sleep function -------------------
:SLEEP
    set /a SECS=%1
    set /a SECS+=1
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n %SECS% -w 1000 > nul
goto :eof